# auth/operation-not-allowed in user signup with Firebase 9 modular api

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

what is a likely cause of `auth/operation-not-allowed` when I enabled account creation and have correct api creds, using

```js
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  updateEmail,
  User,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
} from "firebase/auth";

.
.

    const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
```

I've enabled the operation on the auth methods in the firebase console too

Comment: According to the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors), it indicates that "the provided sign-in provider is disabled for your Firebase project". Can you show a screenshot of the Auth console?

Comment: dang, it was a toggle button, but I didn't notice the save button. Please add it as an answer for posterity ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors), the `auth/operation-not-allowed` error code  indicates that "the provided sign-in provider is disabled for your Firebase project".

You should double-check that you have correctly activated the email/password sign-in provider.

Comment: Thx, also, please firebase don't let us leave the page without saving changes! Or don't use a toggle switch button